# Detecting Multiple/Continous Shakes in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using below code to detect shake on iPhone which works but only for single shake. I am trying to detect and count the number of shakes, if a user continuously shakes the phone.

```
override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake) {
        println("phone shaked")
    }
}
```

Even when i vigorously shake the phone, it only detects one shake.

Comment: The shake is clearly only going to begin once.

Comment: Anyway, you'll probably need to look at the raw accelerometer data.

Comment: I have to stop shaking the iPhone (hold it still for a moment) and then start shaking again so it detects multiple shakes..